# Playing a video without opening another window or having the buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# WinForms application, when you press a button at run-time, the application has to play a video but not in another new window, I want it to be in the form itself, also I don't have to see the Play/Pause/Stop etc. buttons of the Windows Media Player, just to have the video playing and when it ends return to the beginning where the button is situated. I couldn't find a question similar to this one, anyone has any ideas ? If any more information is needed just let me know.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Have a look at `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` object. With it you can embed the Windows Media Player. And you can hide controls, do auto-repeat and such things. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd562388(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: "I couldn't find a question similar to this one...", I've just found 5 different sources in less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Windows Media Player Control:

- You can hide control buttons by setting [`uiMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562469(v=vs.85).aspx) property to `none`.
- You can enable loop mode using [`settings.setMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564867(v=vs.85).aspx) method and  setting `loop` to `true`
- You can set a file path to play, by assign a path to [`URL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562470(v=vs.85).aspx) property.
- Since the [`settings.autoStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564857(v=vs.85).aspx) property is `true` by default, when you set the url, the player plays the media. Also you can use commands like [`Ctlcontrols.play`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562470(v=vs.85).aspx) or [other](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563212(v=vs.85).aspx) control commands.

**Sample Code**

```
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "none";
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("loop", true);
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"d:\video1.wmv";
```

**Resources**

- [How to: Embed Windows Media Player on a Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953.aspx)
- [AxWindowsMediaPlayer Object Properties, Methods and Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562388(v=vs.85).aspx)